# EMMA won't cover one of my projects

Tags: java, ant, junit, code-coverage, emma

I have an issue with EMMA where it is correctly covering all my various Java projects except one.
I am puzzled as to why this occurs as the ANT script appears to be correct. The following expected output is given:

```
 [echo] c:\cc_local_home\emmadata\ProjectName
[instr] processing instrumentation path ...
[instr] instrumentation path processed in 1876 ms
[instr] [84 class(es) instrumented, 0 resource(s) copied]
[instr] metadata merged into [c:\cc_local_home\data\2008-11-17_14.35.19\coverage.emma] {in 62 ms}
```

The above is generated by the following piece of ANT script:

```
<target name="emma" depends="init" if="use.emma">
  <echo message="${emma.bin}" /> 
  <emma enabled="true">
    <instr instrpath="${test.bin}" destdir="${emma.bin}" metadatafile="${test.data.dir}/coverage.emma" merge="true">
      <filter excludes="*Test*,*test*" /> 
      <filter excludes="*Exception" /> 
      <filter excludes="*AppConstants" /> 
    </instr>
  </emma>
</target>
```

After the JUnit tests are run, the following is logged.

emma.report:
   [report] processing input files ...
   [report] 1 file(s) read and merged in 16 ms
   [report] nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files

And no coverage report is generated.

I am certain that the coverage.emma files are being linked correctly so why is EMMA not covering the code?

The `emma.report` task looks like the following:

```
<target name="emma.report" if="use.emma">
  <emma enabled="true">
    <report sourcepath="${test.reports.dir}"> 
      <infileset dir="${test.data.dir}" includes="*.emma" /> 
      <html outfile="${test.reports.dir}/coverage.html" /> 
    </report>
  </emma>
</target>
```

Comment: Same issue here. Perplexingly, running the emma tasks twice generates the report the second time.

Answer (score 1):

What does the `<emma.report>` element look like?

You may want to look at this [FAQ](http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#q.report.noop) concerning this exact message: [Why does <report></report> say "nothing to do: no ...data found in any of the data files" and exit without generating anything?](http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#q.report.noop)

And, as always with `Ant`, turn on `-verbose` and double check the output.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to make sure that the JUnit target is running the instrumented code, and not running non-instrumented code (which would not produce any coverage data).

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="emma.report" if="use.emma">
  <emma enabled="true">
    <report sourcepath="${test.reports.dir}"> 
      <infileset dir="${test.data.dir}" includes="*.emma" /> 
      <html outfile="${test.reports.dir}/coverage.html" /> 
    </report>
  </emma>
</target>
```

Comment: This information is best captured by editing the question and putting it there.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you use wrong command to generate the report. Most of the online tutorial is advocating the wrong(may by old) command, even I got this error when I used below command to generate the report:

{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext>java -cp emma.jar emma report -r html -in coverage.em, {ALFRESCO_HOME}\coverage.ec 
EMMA: processing input files ... 
EMMA: 1 file(s) read and merged in 60 ms 
EMMA: nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files

Correct usage of the command is: 
**{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext>java -cp emma.jar emma report -r txt,html -in {JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage.em -in C:\t1_tempSetup\Alfresco\coverage.ec** 
EMMA: processing input files ... 
EMMA: 2 file(s) read and merged in 70 ms EMMA: writing [txt] report to [{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage.txt] ... 
EMMA: writing [html] report to [{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage\index.html]